# PHP, MYsql, Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS forum_comments (
comment_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
comment_by int(11) NOT NULL,
topic_id int(11) NOT NULL,
parent int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
comment text NOT NULL,
commented_date datetime NOT NULL,
commented_type enum('user','admin') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'user',
level int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
status enum('publish','unpublish','block') NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (comment_id)
)
```

`comment_by` is user id that posted comment
`topic_id` is in which comment has been posted
`parent` is if comment is a reply for other comment
`comment` is comment text
`level` is depth of comment ( 1 to n level), 1 is for first level comment for a topic.

Comment depth can be nth level. I need a query to get comment by topic id.

```
select * from forum_comments where topic_id = 1
```

I want to retrieve all the comment by topic id but comment should have replies that are also stored in comment table with "parent" (parent denotes original comment id to which this reply posted)
and all the comments and replies should be in tree view format because i need to display comments in tree format.

```
1 Comment (main comment with "parent" 0)
  2 reply (reply with "parent" 1)
    3 reply (reply with "parent" 2)
       4 reply (reply with "parent" 3)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think it is already asked atmost half an hour ago..

Comment: yes but i did't get any solution thats why i posted it again.

Comment: Thats not how it works dude...

Comment: Please explain how the `parent` field is used.  Is it the `comment_id` of the parent comment?  Also, how do you determine `level`?  Can you post a sample data set that would demonstrate the data tree that you are trying to create?

Answer (score 0):

So try like this

```
SELECT * FROM forum_comments WHERE comment_id = 1 ORDER BY comment_id ASC
```

or you can try with date also like

```
SELECT * FROM forum_comments WHERE comment_id = 1 ORDER BY comment_date ASC
```

Comment: My problem still exist, can anyone help me?
I have a comments table that has a field "parent" holds the id of parent comment. comments depth can be nth level. suppose i posted a comment and someone replied my comment then again i replied them, so comment depth is 3. so i need to retrieve all comments in multi dimensional array form.